# Can i handle other elements when hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

html,

```
<div id="first">
    <a>Come here</a>
</div>

<div id=second">
    second div
</div>
```

css,

```css
#first a:hover{
    color:green;
    /*i want to do this when hover */
    #second{
        background:green;
    }
}
```

in here, if the user cursor goes to "come here", i want to change the other element #second's background color.

Is this possible using only css? or do i have to use jquery or javascript event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```css
#first:hover + #second{
    background: green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/8rJmC/

Use `~` if `#second` is not directly after `#first`.

Notice that it is impossible to attach the `:hover` event to `a` directly using only CSS. The code above attaches it onto `#first`.

You can do it this way with jQuery if you really have to attach it to `a`:

```
$("#first > a").hover(function(){
    $("#second").css(...);
}, ....);
```

Comment: +1, but note that this isn't working on hover over the anchor, it's on hover anywhere over the first div (including off to the right of the anchor). Quite probably an acceptable compromise for the sake of a simple no-JS solution, but for a more complicated html structure JS would be needed.

Comment: @nnnnnn One big downside of CSS is that it can not search upward (hope they add it in CSS4) and I do agree that for more complicated structure JavaScript will be required.

Comment: Yep. Fortunately jQuery makes this sort of thing very easy if needed.